# ConvertTo changes values after converting to float

Tags: opencv

I'm using the function convertTo to convert a matrix from int to float:

```
    Mat lbp_image_d;
    lbp_image.convertTo(lbp_image_d,CV_32F);
```

However, when I convert the matrix, the values change. Is there any reason for them to change? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I see that the values change using the debugger. I'm using opencv 2.4.5 with VS 2012.

For example, the first 5 values (lbp_image.data) before the conversion are [52,0,0,0,58] and after the conversion are [0,0,80,66,0].

Thanks!

Comment: How do you see that the values change? From what to what?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see that the values change using the debugger. I'm using opencv 2.4.5 with VS 2012.

For example, the first 5 values (lbp_image.data) before the conversion are [52,0,0,0,58] and after the conversion are [0,0,80,66,0].

Comment: `convertTo` is declared as `const`, so it shouldn't happen. It might be something to do with how the debugger shows that information. Try printing the values of `lbp_image` in the console, for example.

Comment: you've got to *cast* the data pointer inside the 'watch' window : `(float*)(mat.data), 5` else, you only see bytes

Answer (score 0):

My bad. As berak pointed out, I need to cast the data pointer inside the 'watch' window by using:

```
(float*)(mat.data), 5
```